# How to make a tblr's cell span multiple columns via tabularray's new interfaces?

Tags: tabularray

How to make a `tblr`'s cell span multiple columns via `tabularray`'s new interfaces?

When the following LaTeX code is compiled with Overleaf's 2022 LuaLaTeX engine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}
{
   hlines={solid},
   vlines={solid},
   cell{1}{1}={c=2}
}
A&B\\
C&D
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

the following table results:

[image: Actual results of cell span]

I find this surprising (in an undesirable way). I expected the following table:

[image: Expected results of cell span]

because I specified `cell{1}{1}={c=2}`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the second `{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}
{
   hlines={solid},
   vlines={solid},
   cell{1}{1}={c=2}{}
}
A&B\\
C&D
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

You can see it in action on p.19 of the tabularray documentation:

```
\begin{tblr}{
 hlines = {white},
 vlines = {white},
 cell{1,6}{odd} = {teal7},
 cell{1,6}{even} = {green7},
 cell{2,4}{1,4} = {red7},
 cell{3,5}{1,4} = {purple7},
 cell{2}{2} = {r=4,c=2}{c,azure7},
}
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   & Delta   \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     & Theta   \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  & Mu      \\
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron & Pi      \\
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     & Upsilon \\
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     & Omega   \\
\end{tblr}
```